# How to know the URL of a saved Photo on my Photo Library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm working on a simple puzzle game that use an image as background of the board game.
Everything works fine, but there are a little thing bothering me. When I take a photo from camera I can save it on my Photo Library but I don't know where it was saved, I mean, what is the exactly URL of my photo.

Here is the code where I save photos:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *) info
{
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    UIImage *originalImage, *editedImage, *imageToSave;

    // Handle a still image capture
    if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

        editedImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        if (editedImage) {
            imageToSave = editedImage;
        } else {
            imageToSave = originalImage;
        }

        CGRect bounds;

        bounds.origin = CGPointZero;
        bounds.size = imageToSave.size;

        [scrollView setContentSize:bounds.size];
        [scrollView setContentOffset:bounds.origin];
        [imageView setFrame:bounds];
        imageView.image = imageToSave;

        if ([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"] == nil) {
            // Save the new image (original or edited) to the Camera Roll
            ALAssetsLibrary *al = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
            ALAssetOrientation orientation; //= [[[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata"] objectForKey:@"Orientation"] integerValue];
            NSString *infoOrientation = [[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata"] objectForKey:@"Orientation"];
            switch ([infoOrientation integerValue]) {
                case 3:
                    orientation = ALAssetOrientationUp;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    orientation = ALAssetOrientationRight;
                    break;
                default:
                    orientation = ALAssetOrientationDown;
                    break;
            }
            [al writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[imageToSave CGImage] orientation:orientation completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                if (error == nil) {
                    NSLog(@"saved");
                    savedImageCam = assetURL;
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"error");
                }
            }];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"URL from saved image: %@", savedImageCam);
            NSLog(@"URL from photo image: %@", [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"]);
        }
    }

    // Handle a movie capture
    if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

        NSString *moviePath = (NSString *)[[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];

        if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
        }
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The call method `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` doesn't return the URL, and the instance variable `info` just bring the URL if I call the Photo Library directly not through of camera.

Anybody knows how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you really want to save the image to the photo library? Why not save the image in the app's sandbox for future reference?

Comment: Yes, really I need to save in photo library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`. Instead, use the `ALAssetsLibrary` and `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:orientation:completionBlock:`. The `completionBlock` then gives you access to the asset URL that you can use to get the image again in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Wain, please view the changes on my code. Now I can know the URL from saved photos.